# How to use for loop to remove drivers from DISM image with batch

Tags: image, batch-file

I built a batch file to remove drivers from an Imagex image. The Image is mounted and then this command is run:

```
forfiles /p C:\Images\Drivers /s /m *.inf /C "cmd /c DISM /Image:C:\Images\Offline /Remove-Driver /Driver:@Path"
```

It seems to search the folder c:\images\offline when it should be searching c:\images\drivers.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `/Image:C:\Images\Offline` tells DISM where the image is mounted and located.

The code `/Remove-Driver /Driver:@Path"` is what tells DISM where the inf to the drivers are to remove.

I was able to use this command to make it work:

```
For /r C:\Images\Drivers %%G in (*.inf) do DISM "/Image:C:\images\Offline" "/Remove-Driver:%%G"`
```

Comment: Nice! Since I already deleted my answer, I edited yours to take out reference to my answer (if my edit goes through). Don't forget to check this as accepted answer.